# I have an interface implemented in an existing WCF service that I can't add a reference for

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I have `ASDService.svc`:

```
 namespace StatusSimulator
 {
      [ServiceContract]
      public class ASDService
      {
           [OperationContract]
           public void DoWork()
      }

      [ServiceContract]
      public interface IScheduleTables
      {
            [OperatonContract]
            string getTable(string l, int r, int c)
            [OperatonContract]
            string getTable(string test)
            [OperatonContract]
            string createTable(List<string> lst, int r, int bal)
      }

      public class ScheduleTables:IScheduleTables
      {
               //Interface Implementation
      }
 }
```

`web.config`:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="NewBehavior0">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="NewBinding0" />
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="NewBehavior0" name="StatusSimulator.ASDService">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:2405/ASDService.svc" binding="basicHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="NewBinding0" name="ASDEndpoint" contract="StatusSimulator.ASDService" />
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:2405/ASDService.svc" binding ="basicHttpBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="NewBinding0" name="ScheduleTableEndPoint" contract="StatusSimulator.IScheduleTables" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Absolutely nothing I've tried will expose the interface to the service. The only thing I can see is `ASDService.DoWork`. How does one implement other classes or interfaces inside a pre-existing service?

I've tried two services in the config, multiple endpoints. I've tried nesting the interface inside ASDService. I've read more tutorials and posts on here than I care to mention. As it sits I am getting the error

> The contract name 'StatusSimulator.IScheduleTables' could not be found in the list of contracts implemented by the service 'ASDService'.

I'm baffled, out of ideas and am going to need professional help if this continues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't be mixing a service contract (defined on the concrete class `ADsService`) with the implementation of another service contract (`IScheduleTables`).

I would recommend that you have **two distinct service contracts** as interfaces (`IASDService` and `IScheduleTables`), and then **one concrete class** that implements both interfaces - something like this:

```
namespace StatusSimulator
{
      [ServiceContract]
      public interface IASDService
      {
           [OperationContract]
           public void DoWork()
      }

      [ServiceContract]
      public interface IScheduleTables
      {
            [OperatonContract]
            string getTable(string l, int r, int c)
            [OperatonContract]
            string getTable(string test)
            [OperatonContract]
            string createTable(List<string> lst, int r, int bal)
      }

      public class ServiceImplementation : IADSService, IScheduleTables
      {
         // implement both interfaces here...
      }
 }
```

As for resources: I would use these for starters:

- [this is the full MSDN documentation on WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456779.aspx)

Then there's a couple of good books - most notably [Learning WCF](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596101627) by Michele Leroux Bustamante. She covers all the necessary topics, and in a very understandable and approachable way. This will teach you everything - basics, intermediate topics, security, transaction control and so forth - that you need to know to write high quality, useful WCF services.

Comment: I see, I did the wizard and then dropped in my code after I got the default working. To be honest I tried commenting out the ASDService class because it isn't needed, but the whole thing stopped working.

Comment: @Bmo: well, in your **config**, you're referring to the `ADSService` (by the `name=` attribute of your `<service>`). If you change that, you need to update the config, too! The service name must **exactly** match the **fully-qualified** class name of the class implementing the service

Comment: `<service behaviorConfiguration="NewBehavior0" name="StatusSimulator.IScheduleTables">` Is giving me `The type 'StatusSimulator.ASDService', provided as the Service attribute value in the ServiceHost directive...could not be found.` So I changed that to `Service="StatusSimulator.IScheduleTables` and it says I can only uses classes. So I changed it to the implementation and I got another error that does on make any sense. Can you recommend a resource to learn, obviously the tutorials I've done so far do not have the detail required to understand, or I need to pick an new career.

Comment: @Bmo: your **ServiceHost** must use the service **implementation** class - same as you have to use in the `<service name="....">` attribute - the fully qualified class name of the implementation class - not any of the interfaces....

Comment: Holy mother of pearl. It's working. More issues included apparently you can't overload. It didn't like getTable(string, string, int) and getTable(string). Changed to getTable2(string). I couldn't make read only properties that had to be changed in my DataContract.

Now time to see if my, what started as an experiment but took two days of intense sighing, even works.

Comment: @Bmo: you're right - WCF methods must have unique names - WCF doesn't support overloading bsaed solely on parameters (number and types)

Comment: Marc, your link is for the German site. Do you have an equivalent for en-US? When I add in en-US, I get to a different page.

Comment: Looks like that link moved. That's the .NET page, not longer the WCF page.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: *it's dead, John* :-)  (with apologies to all Trekkies) - too bad, it had really good video content and articles... but can't find it anymore :-(

Comment: I had actually noticed its absence before, but hoped you had rediscovered the English version :-)